# How to push array of objects to grafana with statsd to create gauge dashboard

Tags: node.js, prometheus, statsd

I want to push with statsd (prometheus) an array of objects containing user_id and other properties specific to said user. The goal is to be able to display on a graph a number of user depending on chosen property. As an example, this is the value I want to push:

```
[
        {
            "user_id": "b3726d1d-e947-4035-bd98-87bddbca1c2b",
            "premium": false,
            "basic": false
        },
        {
            "user_id": "a2b9e909-0e35-48b2-a7d6-0a554f802159",
            "premium": false,
            "basic": true
        },
        {
            "user_id": "1e91df33-122b-4199-adff-a001e7864221",
            "premium": true,
            "basic": false
        }
]
```

And I want to be able to choose premium property in Grafana and get a number of premium users on the graph counted. How can I make it worked? This is how I tried to do it...

In the script that pushes the data, it looks like this:

```
const userStatistics = await UserRepository.getUserStatistics();
statsD.default.gauge("user_statistics", userStatistics);
```

where userStatistics is the value mentioned before. Do I have to also push a number of total users to Grafana, or is this not needed? And if so, do I just push it as a seperate value? As in

```
statsD.default.gauge("totalCountOfUsers", totalCountOfUsers);
```

The idea for it is to be a scalable solution, as I think new properties are also gonna be added in the future, that's why I'm thinking of doing this that way... Anyone could help out with this?

When I tried the solution above, the metrics didn't show up at all.

Comment: Your questions lacks detail making it hard to answer.

Comment: 1. `{"user","premum","basic"}` is not a metric. It represents metadata or tags but it is not a metric because it does not have a value.  See Datadog's documentation on [Metric Types](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/types/?tab=count) for example. Gauges specifically report values that may go up or down. To count users, you likely want to use a Counter instead.

Comment: 2. It's unclear what JavaScript library you're using but it seems unlikely that `statsD.default.gauge()` will work with `userStatistics` if they have the structure you show (there's no value).

Comment: 3. It's unclear why you're using StatsD to push metrics to Prometheus. If you're required to use StatsD that would explain it but, if not, you should consider using a Prometheus client library directly.

Comment: 4. If you were able to push a `number_of_users` metric, tagged with `premium` and `basic` correctly to Prometheus|Grafana then you would be able to query this metric (`number_of_users`) and aggregate it by any subset of those tags.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. If it comes to 2. I'm required to use statsD. I wanted to do it this way, so that It's possible to choose users who have premium AND have some other property. I thought that maybe if I push data like this I will be able to create query that would count user_id's with both properties set as true. If I simply push numbers, you can never make those connections, I would have to push every single combination in the script which I wanted to avoid, hence the question. I thought prometheus/grafana can somehow handle that.

Comment: And I used Gauge, since there is something like <METRIC_TYPE>.count. Thought I can e.g. get users with premium and basic (for the sake of example) and count them in Grafana like this. (https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/types/?tab=histogram#metric-types)

Comment: Understood about being required to use statsd. Metrics general comprise a tuple of name*tags*value. You must have some value (even if implicit). In your case increment a Counter by 1 for each User **or** counting the number of (current) User(s) and setting that total as a the value of a Gauge. Tags are used (e.g. `premium`, `basic`) to identity individual metrics and are used to filter metrics. For example, you may have a metric called `Users` and you would use tags `premium` and `basic`. You probably don't want to include `user_id` as a tag because it's too (!) variable.

Comment: Now, a specific User (measurement) is somewhat binary... the User exists or doesn't. You could use a value of `1.0` for online|logged in and `0.0` for offline|logged out. A specific User would be (in Prometheus) `user{"premium"="false","basic"="false"}`. So you could publish Gauges that provide all permutations of your tags. Then, you would use Prometheus or Grafana to `sum` your metric ignoring (`without`) tags. This would give a total number of users. Then you could `sum` your metric by e.g. `premium=true` yielding the total number of Users with the tag `premium=true`.

Comment: Hey, sorry for radio silence, I managed to make it work, thank you for your help. The solution was to push the data like this: ```statsD.default.gauge(`user_stats, user_id=${user['user_id']}, premium=${user['premium']}, basic=${user['basic']}`, 1);``` in a forEach loop and it works well, although it seems to choke under a huge data load, something for me to still figure out. Anyway, thank you again!